# radio button focused instead of the anchor element (IE9 issue)

Tags: focus, internet-explorer-9, radio-button, anchor

I have an interactive ASP.NET Form that has to work even when Javascript is turned off on a browser. This form has questions that contain yes-no radio buttons. When javascript is turned off, "go to" links (ie. "go to Q2") appear beside these radio buttons which are simple  links that contain href="#id-of-another-element". So when a user clicks on the 'go to' link, the page will focus the anchor element, which is standard browser behaviour.

Firefox, Chrome and Safari does it in a way where if you click on the anchor link, the radio button beside it is not selected automatically - which means there wouldn't be anything preventing the user from being directed to the anchor element. IE9 however does it differently. The radio button gets selected and more importantly focused when you click on the anchor link. This stops the anchor element from being focused. You could see on the address bar however, that the URL has been updated with the anchor tag at the end (ie. http..#id) so that when you refresh the page, you will then be able to go to the link that you were attempting to go to.

My question now is: how do I fix this without javascript so that IE9 users can successfully go to the anchor elements they wanna go to on click of a link even though the radio button is not selected (to make it consistent with the other browsers)?

Comment: Does it happen in both normal and compatibility modes?